# Painting problesh with mesh

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Has anyone encountered such a problem that for some reason a part of the mesh on the render is displayed black and it's impossible to paint on it (I didn't put any mask or smth). The color doesn't apply on the meash, although everything seems to be fine with the UV.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you have overlapping faces?

Comment: No, everything is fine, I checked(

Comment: could you please share the part with the problem? Use a platfrom like workupload and share the link

Comment: yes, sure! here it is https://workupload.com/file/dYS3ZXJNusb but i decided to cut ears and painted them separatly and I have another problem, described it here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311531/missing-object-while-texture-painting?noredirect=1#comment540027_311531

Comment: what is the part you can't paint on? Also you haven't shared the images and your mesh is super dense which is not very convenient for my computer   :((

Comment: sorry I guess I can't fix it then(