# Missing object while texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

For some reason the object dissapears when I swith to Texture Paint, and wehn I try to paint on it apllies like this, what may be the problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the file https://workupload.com/file/w8WuPLNxvBh

Comment: Try Alt-H to unhide it?

Comment: didn't work, i guess it's something with textures, but i don't know what exactly

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. Pack the textures into the Blend file via the File > External Data > Pack Resources menu. If the file size is under 30Meg you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/311531/edit) your question here and paste the link into it. If it's larger, try and reduce the size by deleting objects that aren't causing problems before saving or upload it to an external site such as WeTransfer and add the link inot your question.

Comment: I added the file. If you try to turn texture paint mode then for some reason it's empty..

Comment: Maybe someone else here can have a look because I'm not that familiar with texture painting, but just switching to the Texture Paint layout shows your full model here so I'm not really sure what's going on. You do seem to have quite a few 'Dragon' objects in the outliner and a large number of images in the Image Editor dropdown, so are you sure you're using the correct images with the correct object?

Comment: Probably too much memory being used - I tried opening it and Blender crashed at the onset. If you have multiple meshes present of the same thing, might mean you need to clean your memory by importing a single mesh to paint in a separate file to test.